# Best way to execute powershell script ".ps1"

Tags: powershell

what is the best way to execute .ps1 script?
if I'm a user who has no idea about powershell, but I want to just double click the script and let it run.
could you please advise on the best practice?

Thank you

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $False,        
        ValueFromPipeline = $True, 
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True,         
        HelpMessage = "Provide Files Path.")]
    [string]$FilesPath = 'C:\Users\myusername\OneDrive - mycompany\mycompany\Sales & Marketing\Sales Reports', 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $False,
        ValueFromPipeline = $True,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True,
        HelpMessage = "Provide Sheet Name.")]
    [string]$SheetName = 'Expenses'
)

Try
{
    $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $FilesPath -Include *.xlsx, *.xls, *.xlsm -Recurse 
    $Counter = $Files.Count  
    $Array = @()
    $OutPutFilePath = (Join-Path $FilesPath -ChildPath "Exported-ExcelData.csv")
    Remove-Item -Path $OutPutFilePath -Force  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    ForEach ($File In $Files)
    {                
        Write-Verbose -Message "Accessing File $($File.Name) and Exporting Data from Sheet $SheetName. Remaining $Counter Files." -Verbose 
        $Counter -= 1
        $AllData = Import-Excel -Path $File.FullName -WorksheetName $SheetName -NoHeader
        $i = 0 
        ForEach ($Data In $AllData)
        {
            $ArrayData = "" | Select-Object "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6"
            $ArrayData.P1 = $Data[0].P1
            $ArrayData.P2 = $Data[0].P2
            $ArrayData.P3 = $Data[0].P3
            $ArrayData.P4 = $File.Name
            $ArrayData.P5 = $File.FullName 
            $ArrayData.P6 = ($i += 1)
            $Array += $ArrayData
        }
    }
    $Array | Export-Csv -Path $OutPutFilePath -Append -NoTypeInformation 
}
Catch
{
    $ErrorLog = "Error On " + (Get-Date) + ";$($_.Exception.Message) - Line Number: $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)"
    Write-Error "$($_.Exception.Message) - Line Number: $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)"    
}
Finally
{
    Write-Host "Process has been completed!" -ForegroundColor Green
    Read-Host "Press any key to continue..."
}
```

Comment: [Running PowerShell Scripts Is as Easy as 1-2-3](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-powershell-scripts-easy-1-2-3).

Comment: Closing this as "primarily opinion-based" is asinine. This is about _Best Practice_, i.e. weighing risks and benefits of different methods, and not opinion. The two answers are very good quality and provide Best Practice methods for launching _personal_ powershell scripts inside a user's account, and for _installed_ scripts delivered as a component of a larger piece of software.

Comment: @Rich, yes, it's even kinda scary how there was apparently an entire mob to execute it... :) :-/ Thankfully those very useful answers came first. (If it was about being a better fit for SuperUser, I'd understand. But this...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a batch file.
Launching your PS1 file can be problematic because of the Powershell policy and also, PS1 scripts won't launch by default on a windows machine.

However, if you create a batch file that reference your PS1 script, then you're all set.

The `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` will ignore the current system policy so your script can run without issues.

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'C:\Users\SO\Desktop\YourScript.ps1'"
```

See below two batch command using relative path.

```
# Launch script
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%mypath:~0,-1%\data\install.ps1'"

# Same thing but force the script to run as admin
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -File ""%mypath:~0,-1%\data\install.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

In these two variants, the PS1 I am lauching is in a subfolder called data and script is called install.ps1. 
Therefore, I do not have to hardcode the script path in the batch file (you could put the PS1 at the same level than the batch file. In my example, I actually wanted only the batch at the first folder level and everything else "hidden from view" in a subfolder so the user does not have to think what file to execute.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend compiling the script, I believe that is the only way to reliably double-click a script. There are other ways, but they require weakening security, and partly as a result of this are hard to run across different systems.

The easiest way I've found to compile powershell is by using PowerGUI. You can paste your script and compile a portable .exe file that can be double-clicked. It doesn't require elevated permissions. Their website no longer hosts it, so you will need to find a 3rd party download.

You can also find a Visual Studio extension or one of Sapien's products, however both will cost money and aren't any better for just creating a basic double-clickable script.

Additionally, you will need to modify your script to include a prompt - assuming you wrote your code, that should be easily accomplished. Basically, you need to get it so that you never have to type anything in that you are not directly asked for, if you were to click RUN in ISE.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. what about calling this script from another script, do you know how I can achieve this?

Comment: @Codernator Why would you?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, why _wouldn't_ you? PowerShell ostensibly provides Windows with a strong scripting feature like *NIX, and so this should encourage the creation of small finished components that each do one thing very well, much like `tr` or `grep` (and I know, there are built-in commands for those) and then when creating a larger piece of work, send the data through _pipelines_ of these small, predictable components.

Comment: @Codernator The other pieces would need to be _installed_ at some point in your `PATH`.

Comment: @Rich I was referring to *compiling your scripts*.  Almost any tool that does that just expands the script to a temp directory and runs it normally anyways.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Ah, you'd tagged Codernator, who asked how to call from another script. I was answering that question.